# Is the result of an assignment expression always the value on the right-hand side?

Tags: javascript

In the following code, the object `o` is assigned to `foo` (after the destructuring).

In other words, the result of the assignment expression `({ bar, bam } = o)` is `o`.

```js
const o = { bar: '', bam: '' }
const foo = ({ bar, bam } = o)
console.log(foo === o) // true
```

Is the result of an assignment expression always the value of the expression on the right-hand side?

Comment: No, not when the destructuring does throw an exception :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all in section [12.14.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) of the spec. For the "plain" assignment operator `=`, the value is always the right-hand side. For assignment operators that compute a result, like `+=`, the value of the overall expression is the computed result.

Answer (score 1):

`({ bar, bam } = o)` returns `o` so `foo` is a link to `o`